# How to sync dropbox folder with Amazon S3 in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, dropbox

I want to know if there is a way to sync a dropbox folder with an Amazon S3 folder with java, or if I can sync them via dropbox/s3 commandline clients.

Comment: It's likely you'll have to write your own method of doing this, as it wouldn't be provided by either amazon or Dropbox sdk. If you're looking for some other 3rd party library here, sorry but questions like that are off topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. So, I will build my own method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option to sync directly from Dropbox to Amazon S3.

You can follow what I did.

[image]

We need to write our own crawler. In that managing the sessions between two external endpoint will be challenging.

Please refer this [github](https://github.com/ncw/rclone) link. It might me useful.